# Netbeans + Xdebug + php not working

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

My netbeans does not work the breakpoints using xdebug, my configuration looks correct, so I configured the first time I ran up to stop debugging the first time since then has never worked, someone had this problem? The version of my netbeans is 6.8 and the version of php is 2.5.2.

my php.ini:

```
zend_extension_ts = d:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.2-5.2.5.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
```

Answer (score 10):

In my case this line needed to be included in the php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
```

Here is the configuration section for XDebug:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "d:/wamp/tmp"
```

Comment: I used Ubuntu, and I couldn't start it. I added all the lines except the last 2 to /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini after install xdebug (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504152/is-it-possible-to-use-xdebug-on-ubuntu) and worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

**Checklist for xdebug:**

1. Check that xdebug is loaded in `phpinfo()`, and the runtime value [matches expected configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20746525/893578).
2. `xdebug.remote_enable` [is `on`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347864/893578).
3. `xdebug.extended_info` [should be `on`](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#extended_info) for breakpoints to work.
4. `xdebug.remote_port` must be same as ide [and unused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17398288/893578).
5. `xdebug.remote_handler` is `dbgp`.
6. `xdebug.idekey` should be set to [same as ide's key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28715023/893578) if `xdebug.remote_autostart` is on.
7. Sometimes it help to set `xdebug.remote_host` to intranet IP or computer name instead of local ip 127.0.0.1.  PHP must be [allowed by Firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24711351/893578) to connect to this host and port.
8. Setting `xdebug.remote_log` to a file will help in checking what is wrong. Disable the log once debug is working.

**Sample config:**

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.extended_info=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

**Checklist for NetBeans:**

1. Firewall must allow Netbeans to listen for connection with configured host.
2. Tools -> Options -> PHP -> Debugging, check port.  Also check session id if xdebug.remote_autostart is on.
3. Project type must be PHP.
4. Project Properties -> Source, [web root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24578833/893578) must be correct.
5. Project Properties -> Run Configuration, index file need to be a php (or empty) for Ctrl+F5 to work.
6. Project Properties -> Run Configuration -> Advanced, debug url [should be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22514048/893578) "Default" or "Ask Everytime".
7. Project Properties -> Run Configuration -> Advanced, [path mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8251293/893578) must be correct. (e.g. empty if there are no mappings)

(Most default options work out of the box, so if you are desperate try to delete and recreate the project.)

**False Instructions**, tested on PHP 5.5 and xdebug 2.2:

1. PHP `output_buffering` does not need to be off. (But may help in debugging)
2. OPCache (Zend Cache) module can be loaded.
3. `xdebug.profiler_enable` can be enabled.

Please edit this answer if you found something new.

Answer (score 1):

- Check that you have the right version of Xdebug for your version of PHP (including Thread-safe/non-thread-safe and 64bit/32bit).
- In some newer versions of PHP, you need to use zend_extension, not zend_extension_ts, regardless of whether you have the TS version of Xdebug.

Comment: I have looked at this, and everything seems correct.
The first time I used it all worked perfectly, but then stopped working.

I do not know what to do ...

Comment: I was going to comment but it was too long and comments are not correctly formatted, so I made another "Answer"

Answer (score 1):

(I am replying with an Answer since the formatting in comments wasn't working properly)

Same happened for me: worked once and then stopped. However, I reached a point in my config where it started working without problems and I can share.

First I moved on top of php.ini the ioncube loader:

```
[PHP]
zend_extension=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/zend/lib/ioncube_loader_dar_5.2.so
```

Then I put these lines in the xdebug config:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

And commented out all the lines about Zend Optimizer

```
[Zend]
;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.3
;zend_optimizer.version=3.3.3
```

I work on MAMP, this is why the paths to my libraries are referred to my MAMP folder.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you are still stuck you could try the following:

- Download a new version of xdebug via the wizard (http://www.xdebug.org/wizard.php) and if you follow the instructions maybe you will be lucky.
- Switching off the firewall might help.
- Use a different port in netbeans, for instance in my case using **9001** in netbeans and **9000** in xdebug worked.
- Add to **php.ini** file: `xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug`.
- Find out if you have a **xdebug.ini** file and add the xdebug related php.ini lines to that file.

Always make sure that you restart your apache service to test everything.

Answer (score 1):

`zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll"xdebug.remote_enable = 1 xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"xdebug.remote_host = "localhost" xdebug.remote_port="9000" xdebug.remote_mode=req xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp" xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"`

this is working for me..

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I was able to get it to work w/ mulitple PHP-FPM homebrew installations.

I used this excellent article for the multiple installations:

https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew

In the comments of that post you'll see recommended how to install xdebug, **bottom line:**

```
brew install php56-xdebug
```

You have to install xdebug for each verions of PHP you have installed. Homebrew will make a xdebug.ini file for each version of php you installed. Each will have a path like:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/<version # i.e. "5.6">/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
```

This article installs DNSMasq which runs on xdebug's default port (9000), so you'll need to change the xdebug port to something else (9001 works fine.)

Edit the above mentioned ext-xdebug.ini file (or files if you installed more than one version of php.) Here's what works for me:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-xdebug/xdebug.so"

; General config
; Dumps local variables on exception
xdebug.show_local_vars=On
; Dump server variables
xdebug.dump.SERVER=*
; Dump global variables
xdebug.dump_globals=On
xdebug.collect_params=4;

; Tracing
;xdebug.auto_trace=On
;xdebug.trace_output_dir= /opt/local/php_traces/
xdebug.show_mem_delta=On
xdebug.collect_return=On


; Debugging. You might need to specify your host with some additional options
xdebug.remote_enable=1
: from http://devzone.zend.com/1147/debugging-php-applications-with-xdebug/
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

The first two lines are all that is in the original homebrew file.

BTW  - when I installed multiple PHP versions, this ext-xdebug.ini file was only created for the first PHP version I installed. I simply copied this file to the other PHP version locations, and changed the "php56-xdebug" part of the path in line 2 to reflect the proper php version.

Notice "xdebug.remote_port=9001"

Then in Netbeans (I'm using 8.02 Mac osX10.10.3) I use the following settings.
Go to Preferences->PHP->Debugging

Debugger Port: **9001**

Stop at First Line: (**unchecked**)

Watches & Balloon Evaluation: (**checked** - there's a warning but it works fine for me.)

Also worth noticing is that in order for xdebug to show up using phpinfo() (or command line php -i) I need to restart apache with:

```
launchctl unload -Fw ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php56.plist

sudo apachectl restart

launchctl load -Fw ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php56.plist
```

For some reason my setup requires me to run this every time I startup. Kind of a pain, but I incorporated it in a shell command to easily switch between versions.

One more hint: part of brew info php56 says:

```
OS X 10.8 and newer come with php-fpm pre-installed, to ensure you are using
the brew version you need to make sure /usr/local/sbin is before /usr/sbin
in your PATH:

  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Until I added this to my .profile_bash file, changes I made to each version's php-fpm.conf file were not recognized. Everything else seemed to work so it was confusing.

Hope this saves someone else time & trouble.

Answer (score 0):

In my case - host is on another server, Net-beans 11 - I need to open terminal to remotehost

*Window -> IDE Tools -> Terminal -> Remote Terminal*

P.S. If u type *export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug"* in that terminal, and start debugging session, u can debug console scripts