# Force Logging of All Page Processes & Results

Tags: php, mysql, loops, logging, out-of-memory

I have a particular PHP page that is hanging and I don't know why. Is there a simple way to explicitly log everything that is happening on that page to a log file?

I used to get an `out of memory` error but I increased the limit and now that is no longer an issue. There is a very big loop in there but I can tell when the database records have all been updated so I don't know why the page is staying active. Is there a better way to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PHP debugger like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Or yes, you **can** log to a file if you really want to.

Comment: which led me to the ubuntu apt-get install here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504152/is-it-possible-to-use-xdebug-on-ubuntu