# PHP Error Reporting to Screen, with Line Breaks

Tags: php, error-reporting, error-log

I have setup error reporting in the top of my script to

```
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);
// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  //On or Off
```

The reporting is being logged/saved to my error log file with line breaks, but displays on the screen as 1 continuous line without breaks.

Screen-output example:

```
Warning: getimagesize(i): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 48 Warning: Division by zero in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 49 Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(i): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 62 Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 64 Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 66 Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 72
```

Error-log file example:

```
[22-May-2014 16:42:32 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Warning:  getimagesize(i): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 48
[22-May-2014 16:42:32 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 49
[22-May-2014 16:42:32 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(i): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 62
[22-May-2014 16:42:32 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Warning:  imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 64
[22-May-2014 16:42:32 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Warning:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 66
[22-May-2014 16:42:32 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Warning:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xyzxyz/public_html/fetcher.php on line 72
```

Is there any way to make the output to screen display with line breaks too, so that it will be easier to read it?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use Ctrl+U or install xdebug (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504152/is-it-possible-to-use-xdebug-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks, @oliver.nadj, nice workaround. I fixed it by adding `ini_set('html_errors', true);` to the top of my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use line breaks or HTML in your code to drop in what you need between warnings and errors:

```
$error = "some warning";
echo $error;
echo $error;
```

Will output:

```
some warningsome warning
```

However, you can add a BR to it to display properly in a browser:

```
$error = "some warning";
echo $error."<br />";
echo $error."<br />";
```

Which will output the following in a browser:

```
some warning
some warning
```

Alternately, you can use non html line breaks if you are using a terminal, or outputting text to the screen (rather than HTML):

```
$error = "some warning";
echo $error."\r\n";
echo $error."\r\n";
```

Which will put in line breaks into normal text.

You can mix and match these together to suit your needs. The other thing you can do is use `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags around your error messages so that they display into a browser and/or text file as the error message itself reads:

```
$error = "some warning";
echo "<pre>";
echo $error;
echo $error;
echo "</pre>";
```

Edit: If you are generating many warnings/errors that you aren't actually displaying on purpose, you can also modify the following:

```
html_errors = 1
```

in your PHP.ini file which will output things into a [nice HTML format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. errors are generated by the PHP engine, they are not part of the code. So how can I format them with br or \r\n?

Comment: @CreativeMind I thought you were outputting the errors manually via checks. I added an edit for the auto-generated PHP stuff.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I added `ini_set('html_errors', true);` to the top of my script and it now generates the output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To properly display line breaks in browser, I have the following in my index.php  (PHP7.4)

```php
ini_set('error_prepend_string', '<pre>');
ini_set('error_append_string', '</pre>');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Furthermore, to wrap the text to screen width, replace the first `ini_set` with

```php
ini_set('error_prepend_string', '<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap;">');
```