# xdebug does not activate the breakpoint

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, xdebug

I am using Netbeans to do my project(codeigniter) and my xdebug is configured in php ini. The following are the setting:

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_log="C:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
```

Php info shows that xdebug is activated. I set the breakpoint at on of the variable in the login method and started to debug. The link at the login page appears:

localhost/goldilock/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

After login in, the breakpoint is not activated and I can't debug and the XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug part of the link disappears.

Is there any way the debugging can be activated. I can't find any solution to activate the debugger to the breakpoint.

The xdebug.log says the following:

```
Log opened at 2013-07-01 05:40:22
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2013-07-01 05:40:23

Log opened at 2013-07-01 05:40:35
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2013-07-01 05:40:36

Log opened at 2013-07-01 05:40:38
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2013-07-01 05:40:39

Log opened at 2013-07-01 05:40:39
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2013-07-01 05:40:40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did with the help of Derick's answer:

Step 1: Change xdebug.remote_port=9000 to xdebug.remote_port=9001

Step 2:

1. Change the debugging port in Netbeans. Go to Tools >> Options >> Click PHP tab
2. Under PHP tab click debugging
3. Change the debugger port : 9001
4. Change Session ID : netbeans-xdebug

Step 3: Restart server and netbeans

Step 4: Set a breakpoint and try

Comment: After a few days trying to get xdebug to connect to Netbeans, this saved me. Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do need to turn on `xdebug.remote_enable=1` — without that, debugging is not activated and it will not work.

For requests after the first "login", `xdebug.remote_autostart` should deal with that, but it is possible that Netbeans doesn't accept the new incoming debugging connection. To find out what Xdebug is trying to do, add the setting `xdebug.remote_log=c:\temp\xdebug.log` and investigate what's in the log. (You might have to change the path).

Comment: I have edited the question. Please help me explain the log. Thank you.