# Xdebug Client do not hit breakpoint

Tags: php, xampp, sublimetext3, xdebug

I try to configure Xdebug Client for Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10 (with PHP Version 7.3.0 and 2.7.0RC2 Xdebug version).

I read issues for days because the panels context were always blank, but I solved it adding `"super_globals": false` in Xdebug.sublime-settings.
Now the Xdebug Context show:

[image]

The problem is the breakpoint never hits. never show me the Steps options (into, over). Even, don't show the little yellow arrow on left side.

I believe that it's related to path_mapping configure, but this really confuse me.
I dont understand why I need configure `path_mapping` if I work only on localhost on xampp.

php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.0RC2-7.3-vc15.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.report_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.idekey = sublime.xdebug
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_log = "C:\xampp\php\tmp\xdebug.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`. Per the XDebug documentation:

> **xdebug.remote_autostart** 
> Type: *boolean*, Default value: *0*
>  
>   Normally you need to use a specific HTTP GET/POST variable to start remote
>   debugging (see Remote Debugging). When this setting is set to 1,
>   Xdebug will always attempt to start a remote debugging session and try
>   to connect to a client, even if the GET/POST/COOKIE variable was not
>   present.

See: [XDEBUG EXTENSION FOR PHP | DOCUMENTATION](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote)
Of course, restart your server after adding.

EDIT: See also Derick's answer on this [StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382163/xdebug-does-not-activate-the-breakpoint?rq=1) about using a log file to troubleshoot, if the above doesn't work.